# Data Binding in WPF User Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I am creating a UserControl for a series of controls shared by several windows. One of the controls is a Label which shows the flow of some other process in terms of "protocol numbers".

I am trying to offer DataBinding with this Label so the Window automatically reflects the state of the process as the protocol number variable changes.

This is the User control XAML:

```
<UserControl Name="MainOptionsPanel"
    x:Class="ExperienceMainControls.MainControls"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    >
<Label Height="Auto" Name="numberLabel">Protocol:</Label>
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ProtocolNumber}" Name="protocolNumberLabel"/>
(...)
</UserControl>
```

And this is the Code-Behind:

```
public partial class MainControls 
{
    public MainControls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int ProtocolNumber
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ProtocolNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProtocolNumberProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ProtocolNumberProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register("ProtocolNumber", typeof(int), typeof(MainControls));
}
```

This seems to be working because if on the constructor I set ProtocolNumber to an arbitrary value, it is reflected in the user control.

However, when using this usercontrol on the final window, the data binding breaks.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlTesting.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:expControl="clr-namespace:ExperienceMainControls;assembly=ExperienceMainControls"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    >
    <StackPanel>
        <expControl:MainControls ProtocolNumber="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Code-Behind for window:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        Number= 15;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This sets the Protocol Number to zero, ignoring the value set to Number.

I've read example

Comment: in your output window you will see a binding error, something like object MainOptionsPanel has no Property Number - and thats true. simply change your usercontrol xaml to that in my answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

if you look at your output window you should see the binding exception.

The problem you have is the following: within your usercontrol you will bind the label to the DP ProtocolNumber of your usercontrol and not the `DataContext`, so you have to add for example the element name to the binding.

```
<UserControl Name="MainOptionsPanel"
    x:Class="ExperienceMainControls.MainControls"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="uc"
    >
<Label Height="Auto" Name="numberLabel">Protocol:</Label>
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ProtocolNumber, ElementName=uc}" Name="protocolNumberLabel"/>
(...)
</UserControl>
```

EDIT: to clear some things up, your usercontrol also works if you change the binding in your MainWindow. but you have to bind to the DataContext of the MainWindow with RelativeSource.

```
    <expControl:MainControls ProtocolNumber="{Binding Path=Number, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Answer (score 9):

What you have in effect:

```
<expControl:MainControls DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                         ProtocolNumber="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

=> Do **not** set the `DataContext` in `UserControl` declarations, use `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` bindings instead.

Comment: Why not set the DataContext? I know there are ways it propagates to child controls (I think) but we haven't ran into any troubles so far in our application.

Comment: @mizipzor: It's bad practice, setting the DataContext like that is  invisible "from the outside" and impractical as inheritance of the DataContext is usually what you want and expect.

Comment: Actually, inheritance of the DataContext is (thus far) not what I want. CustomControls is another story. But for UserControls I'll argue its good practice.

Comment: So what you're saying is to remove the DataContext line from Usercontrol definition? Because there I also defined it as RelativeSource.

Comment: @kelmer: Yes. It't the same object, anything you do in the definition applies to your instances, which in the case of setting a DataContext, as you just have shown, is a bad idea as it overwrites the inherited DataContext.

Comment: @mizipzor: It's not good practice, seriously, this question is proof enough. If you so far had no problems with that you are probably using UserControls in a way that was not quite intended.

Comment: I removed the dataContext line and still does not work. I get the following error:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'Number' property not found on 'object' ''MainControls' (Name='MainOptionsPanel')'. BindingExpression:Path=Number; DataItem='MainControls' (Name='MainOptionsPanel'); target element is 'MainControls' (Name='MainOptionsPanel'); (...)`

Could this be cause by this line?

`public static DependencyProperty ProtocolNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ProtocolNumber", typeof(int), typeof(MainControls));`

Comment: Just use whatever is simple. This maniac idea of putting everything in xaml is non-sense and it actually makes reading the whole thing way more difficult, not to mention that the bindings syntax is a complete mess.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not specifying the `RelativeSource` of the binding, try set the `DataContext` in the constructor:

```
    public Window1()
    {
        Number= 15;
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: To be honest this approach is bad because you can change data context from the outside.