# DataBinding on Custom Control Not Working

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, custom-controls

I'm sure I am doing something wrong.

Some context: WPF application, MVVM, Entity Framework, etc.

In my ViewModel for a window, I have two properties: `MemberCount` and `EventCount`. Both are `int`.

In my view, I have a 5 instances of a custom control. This custom control has three dependency Properties: `ImageData`, `ButtonText`, and `ButtonSubText`. All are `string`.

What I want to do is bind the control in such a way that `MemberCount` is bound to the `ButtonText` property on one control, and `EventCount` is Bound to `ButtonText` property on another control.

So I do something along the lines of:

```
<control:MyControl ... ButtonText="{Binding MemberCount, Mode=OneWay}" ButtonSubText="Members"  Background="{DynamicResource MetroRed}" />
```

The `DataContext` of my window is set to the correct ViewModel.

No matter what I try, I cannot get the member count or event count to show up on the control. I get an error in the output window:

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MemberCount' property
 not found on 'object' ''MyControl' (Name='button')'. BindingExpression:Path=MemberCount;
 DataItem='MyControl' (Name='button'); target element is 'MyControl' (Name='button');
 target property is 'ButtonText' (type 'String')
```

I am getting used to `DataBinding` in WPF, but for the life of me, I can't figure this one out.

What do I need to do to be able to bind a property from my view model to a property on my custom control?

Comment: The easiest way is to always check this with snoop, check if you have the correct DataContext on the controls where you try to bind to a property. The error says that Membercount was not found on MyControl, which means that you somewhere set the DataContext to an actual control instance, and not your ViewModel.

Comment: Sure enough... I have no idea how or why, but the DataContext of the custom control was set to itself. I removed it and had to play with the dependency property on the control, but it works great now! Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: **DataItem='MyControl'**

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is the datacontext or binding within your usercontrol. you should post your usercontrol code.

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="uc">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=uc,Path=ButtonText}/>
</MyUserControl>
```

check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566632/wpf-simple-usercontrol-and-mvvm-pattern-how-to-use/11574219#11574219), there is a similar problem.