# Usercontrol using wrong Datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties, datacontext

I have a UserControl that is used in a parent control in this way:

```
<Views:TranslationTextInput  Translation="{Binding SelectedEntity.Name}"/>
```

The parent control DataContext is a ViewModel containing the SelectedEntity Property.

In my child UserControl I define a new ViewModel as the DataContext:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
      <vm:TranslationTextInputViewModel x:Name="vm"></vm:TranslationTextInputViewModel>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

In the code behind I have:

```
    public static readonly  DependencyProperty TranslationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Translation", typeof(Translation),typeof(UserControl));

    // .NET Property wrapper
    public Translation Translation
    {
        get { return (Translation)GetValue(TranslationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TranslationProperty, value); }
    }


 public TranslationTextInput(){
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new TranslationTextInputViewModel();
     SetBinding(TranslationProperty,   new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath     ("Translation"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource });
```

When executed I get a Binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedEntity' property not found on 'object' ''TranslationTextInputViewModel' (HashCode=49954236)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedEntity.Name; DataItem='TranslationTextInputViewModel' (HashCode=49954236); target element is 'TranslationTextInput' (Name='InputControl'); target property is 'Translation' (type 'Translation')
```

It seems the SelectedEntity is looked up on the child UserControl's Viewmodel, but the Property of the parent ViewModel should be used. How can I solve this?

Edit:

```
    public TranslationTextInputViewModel()
    {
        //EnglishTranslation = tranlsations["en"];
    }

    public string EnglishTranslation
    {
        get
        {
            if (!Translation.TranslationDict.ContainsKey(new CultureInfo("en").LCID))
                Translation.Translations.Add(new TranslationItem() { Text = "", Lcid = new CultureInfo("en").LCID });
            return Translation.TranslationDict[new CultureInfo("en").LCID].Text;
        }
        set
        {
            Translation.TranslationDict[new CultureInfo("en").LCID].Text = value;
        }

    }

    public string SelectedTranslation
    {
        get
        {
            if (!Translation.TranslationDict.ContainsKey(_selectedLanguage))
                Translation.Translations.Add(new TranslationItem() { Text = "", Lcid = _selectedLanguage });
            return Translation.TranslationDict[_selectedLanguage].Text;

        }

        set
        {
            Translation.TranslationDict[_selectedLanguage].Text = value;
        }
    }

    private Translation _translation;

    public Translation Translation
    {
        get
        {
            if (_translation == null)
                _translation = new Translation();
            return _translation; }
        set { _translation = value; }
    }

    private int _selectedLanguage;
    public int SelectedLanguage
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedLanguage;
        }
    }

    public List<CultureInfo> AvailableLanguages
    {
        get
        {

            return (from x in PqsLocalization.AvailableLanguages where x.Name != "en" select x).ToList();
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand<int> LanguageChanged { get; private set; }


    private void LanguageChangedExecute(int lang)
    {
        _selectedLanguage = lang;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedLanguage");
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTranslation");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't ever set the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` from inside the `UserControl`. By doing so, you are preventing any other `DataContext` from getting passed to the `UserControl`, which kind of defeats one of WPF's biggest advantages of having separate UI and data layers.

When your UserControl is being created, you are setting the `DataContext` to a new `TranslationTextInputViewModel`, and `TranslationTextInputViewModel` does not have a property called `SelectedEntity`, so your binding fails.

My suggestion? Don't set the `DataContext` in the `UserControl`.

If you want a specific ViewModel to be used for a specific UserControl, add that to your `ParentViewModel` and pass it in as the `DataContext`, such as this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TranslationTextInputViewModel}">
        <Views:TranslationTextInput />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

or this:

```
<Views:TranslationTextInput 
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedTranslationTextInputViewModel}" />
```

Or if your `ViewModel` contains functionality specific to the `UserControl` itself and should not be part of your application layer, put that code in the code-behind the `UserControl` and get rid of the `ViewModel` altogether.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your explanation. The Viewmodel would have contained only functionality of the control (Selected Language ...). Would you suggest i simply create propterys in code behind, implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface and bind my fields to code behind without setting DataContext?

Comment: If other parts of the application can influence that value, I would make those `DependencyProperties` so that whoever uses the control can set the value. If they are only used internally within the Control, I'd question the need for having them at all, because it sounds like they should either be static, or be based on some UI object inside the `UserControl` and you can bind directly to the UI element containing the property.

Comment: Other parts of the Application can not change those properties. Though i also can't bind directly to ui components. A Translation item (dependency Property) has a Dictionary storing different Translations. In my User control i have a textbox and a set of Buttons (one for each language). If a button is clicked it should get checked if is already part of the Dictionary and if not is added. Then the Translation for the selected Language is shown. What is your proposal for that issue? Thanks in advance?

Comment: @TheJoeIaut I'm not sure of your exact situation, but personally if the `Translation` property being passed to the UserControl contained a Dictionary of languages, I would write the Language Buttons in the `UserControl` using an `ItemsControl` bound to that list. If the dictionary of languages should be defined in the UserControl, I would remove it from the `Transation` object entirely and put it in the `UserControl's` code-behind.

Comment: (cont) Or if languages really have to be defined in both the `Translation` object and the `UserControl`, I would either add the functionality to the code-behind the UserControl, or add an `AddLanguage` command to the `Translation` object that your UI buttons could bind to, and pass it the language to add if necessary as the `CommandParameter`. For example, I might have the `Translation` object contain `OriginalText`, `TranslatedText` (bound to your `TextBox`), `ObservableCollection<Language>`, `ICommand AddLanguage(language)`, and `ICommand TranslateText(language)`

Comment: I have posted my Old Viewmodel in the startpost. The Flags are already displayed through an ItemsControl and were Bound to the LanguageChanged in the ViewModel. What i don't get is how it should look without a viewmodel. Shall die Textbox still be bound to the current Translation (Property in Code behind?)? Should the Command defined be in the same way in code behind?

Comment: What is does your `Translation` dependency property consist of? If it's just a string that you can translate, I would put everything else in the code-behind and get rid of the `ViewModel` entirely. Bind an `ItemsControl` to an `ObservableCollection<Language>` in the constructor that defines the available languages, and make the `Button` go to a command that translates the string dependency property into the selected language, and set that string directly to the `TranslatedLanguageTextBox.Text`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Views:TranslationTextInput  Translation="{Binding SelectedEntity.Name}" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you set the `DataContext` your bindings will use it, so I would expect this behaviour -- looking for `SelectedEntity.Name` on the `TranslationTextInputViewModel`.

There are a few ways to get this working. Personally, I like to model these relationships in the view-models themselves (view-models with view-model properties), but in this situation I'd probably try this, as unpleasant as it feels:

```
<Views:TranslationTextInput 
    Translation="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEntity.Name,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                  AncestorType=ParentControlType}}" />
```

Comment: Is having a viewmodel behind a (reusable) usercontrol the way i did correct? It feels it isn't supposed to be this way...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set the **TranslationTextInput.DataContext** to **TranslationTextInputViewModel** in the constructor.