# How to bind a child `UserControl`'s Dependency Property, using `Style`, to a property of the host element's view-model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-style

How to bind a child `UserControl`'s Dependency Property, using `Style`, to a property of the host element's view-model?

I tried the code below, and `MyBlock.BlockIsOnlyOne` should be bound to the view-model's property - `MyContainerViewModel.ViewModelIsOnlyOne`, via the `Style`'s `Setter`. But from some reason it just doesn't work - the `MyBlock.BlockIsOnlyOne`'s value never changes, although the `MyContainerViewModel.ViewModelIsOnlyOne` changes...

The Container XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNs.MyContainer"
             ...
             >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vc:MyContainerViewModel x:Name="TheDataContext"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type vc:MyBlock}">
                <Setter Property="BlockIsOnlyOne" Value="{Binding ViewModelIsOnlyOne}"/>
                <!-- Tried this too, with no success: -->
                <!-- <Setter Property="BlockIsOnlyOne" Value="{Binding ViewModelIsOnlyOne, ElementName=TheDataContext}"/> -->
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        ...
        <vc:MyBlock DataContext="{Binding PortA[0]}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Container's `ViewModel` (only the important part...):

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedAspect] // handles the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation...
class MyContainerViewModel{
    ...
    public bool ViewModelIsOnlyOne { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

The `MyBlock` `UserControl`:

```
class MyBlock : UserControl{
    ...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BlockIsOnlyOneProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BlockIsOnlyOne", typeof (bool), typeof (MyBlock), 
        new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), BlockIsOnlyOne_PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void BlockIsOnlyOne_PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs a)
    {
        var @this = dependencyObject as MyBlock;
        if (@this == null) return;
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Old: {0}, New: {1}", a.OldValue, a.NewValue)); // never seems to fire...
    }

    public bool BlockIsOnlyOne
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(BlockIsOnlyOneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BlockIsOnlyOneProperty, value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Try using a relative source binding instead... something like `{Binding DataContext.ViewModelIsOnlyOne, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyNs.MyContainer}}}`. The first syntax won't work because the `DataContext` for MyBlock is `PortA[0]`, which doesn't have a property called `ViewModelIsOnlyOne`, and my best guess is the second can't find the `DataContext` by name like that... I'm not sure since I almost never hardcode a DataContext like that. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12820041/302677) if you're interested in why it's a bad idea :)

Comment: See my answer to [Sheridan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27506629/587467) below - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505866/how-to-bind-a-child-usercontrols-dependency-property-using-style-to-a-pro#comment43443322_27506629

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by creating a DP on the container... that's not necessary. The idea is you're creating a binding, setting it's source to the first `MyNs.MyContainer` that it finds further up the UI tree, and binding to the `DataContext.ViewModelIsOnlyOne` property of it, which should be a valid property based on what you've posted in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reach your view model property from the `UserControl` using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx). The idea is to search for the parent *view* that the view model is set as the `DataContext` using the `AncestorType` property... try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type vc:MyBlock}">
    <Setter Property="DataContext.BlockIsOnlyOne" Value="{Binding ViewModelIsOnlyOne, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</Style>
```

If that picks up the child `UserControl.DataContext` instead, then you could either set the [`RelativeSource.AncestorLevel` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestorlevel(v=vs.110).aspx) to the appropriate level, or use the name/type of your parent `UserControl` instead:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type vc:MyBlock}">
    <Setter Property="BlockIsOnlyOne" Value="{Binding DataContext.ViewModelIsOnlyOne, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:MyContainer}}}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It works, but only if I create a `Dependency Property` in the container... it doesn't work directly to the view-model (i.e. I have to create a DP in the container, and artificially bind it to the view-model of the container, it's kinda twisted...) no way directly to the view-model, bypassing the container...

Comment: Hold on... this isn't quite right... still looking at it.

Comment: @Sheridan Your `DataContext.` is in the wrong position. It should be in the binding path, not the property path I believe. Also, I'd recommend using the `MyNs.MyContainer` class name rather than the generic `UserControl` in the RelativeSource binding to make sure you get the right item in the UI hierarchy :)

Comment: Kudos! I missed the `DataContext.` in the `Value="{Binding DataContext.ViewModelIsOnlyOne, ...`. Thanks a lot!