# WPF: XAML: Give DataContext a name without instantiating it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my XAML I have a `UserControl1` which I am trying to bind to the `MainWindowViewModel` of `MainWindow`:

```
<ControlLib:UserControl1 Hotzenplotz="{Binding Raeuber, ElementName=vm}" />
```

`Hotzenplotz` is a `DependenyProperty` of `UserControl1`. `Raeuber` is a property of `MainWindowViewModel`.

The catch is the `ElementName=vm` because I don't want XAML to look up the property in `UserControl1` but in my `MainWindowViewModel`

If I bind my `MainWindowViewModel` like this everything is peachy:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="vm" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Unfortunately I can't instantiate `MainWindowViewModel` on-the-fly, I need to bind it from the code side. But then I cannot figure out on how to give the `DataContext` property the name `vm` for future reference.

**Edit**

I solved it this way. I added a name to the `MainWindow`

```
<Window x:Name="mw"
```

And access the binding with the help of the `DataContext` property

```
<ControlLib:UserControl1 Hotzenplotz="{Binding Path=DataContext.Raeuber, ElementName=mw}" />
```

But is this really the correct way?

**Edit 2**

The working code is available here: http://doena-soft.de/tmp/SubControls.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution here: [Binding between my usercontrol and ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404337/binding-between-my-usercontrol-and-viewmodel)

I had the `UserControl1` bound to its own `DataContext` like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Instead now I gave the `UserControl1` inside its own XAML a name "uc" and referred all bindings there to this element name.

Inside `UserControl1` before:

```
<Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding Hotzenplotz}" />
```

And after

```
<Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding Hotzenplotz, ElementName=uc}" />
```

For completeness' sake, here is the second solution: http://doena-soft.de/tmp/SubControls_better.zip