# How to set DataContext to self

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My UserControl requires binding to the ancestor (the ancestor being the MainWindow) and to itself (it's code behind).

To bind to the ancestor, I'm using

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=Window}}">
```

To bind a control to the code behind (and thus using the 'local' DataContext), I'm using

```
<TextBlock Text ="{Binding MyUC3Property}" Name="MyName" />
```

and in the code behind, setting it like

```
this.MyName.DataContext = this;
```

The above works fine, where I can bind to the codebehind and to the ancestor.

Now, I still want to bind to the code behind and the ancestor but set the DataContext in the XAML only (if possible).

I've tried

```
<TextBlock Text ="{Binding MyUC3Property}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
```

and ensured the constructor does not set the DataContext (since I want it all done in the XAML) - (although even if I do set `this.DataContext = this;` the error persists)

and the output window tells me there is a binding error.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyUC3Property' property not found on 'object' ''TextBlock' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MyUC3Property; DataItem='TextBlock' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

I guess I'm missing something obvious, but I can't tell what.

Comment: *What* binding error is there? What is the error message?

Comment: In the constructor of the window / control set `this.DataContext = this;`

Comment: I presume you renamed `MyUC3Property` into `MyLocalProperty` for the sample source code in the question?

Comment: @RononDex I did try this, but how will it help? It will 'overwrite' that I do want binding to the parent.

Comment: @DaveRook Hope this pdf will be helpful to you http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Comment: So you have other controls that are binded to properties not in code behind?

Comment: I am still not sure I understand what you want to bind to. `MyUC3Property` is a property of the user control, it seems (the "local code-behind")? If so, isn't that exactly what the "parent" is, like in your first example? `Self` in the `TextBox` is the `TextBox` itself.

Comment: Yes. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220448/is-a-god-viewmodel-desired-in-wpf for a picture, all my usercontrols are binding to a parent. I now want to bind to the parent and to the code behind.

Comment: @DaveRook: What is the difference between the "parent" and the "code-behind"? Both denote the very same user control, don't they?

Comment: Sorry, I should be using the term ancestor. Yes, @O.R.Mapper, 'MyUC3Property' is local to the UserControl. The issue is, my DataContext of the UserControl is already set to the Ancestor. So, I need a way of setting just the Textbox Datacontext to use the code behind of the UserControl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to bind to the user control the same way as you do to the window:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

What you have tried was referring to the relative source `Self` from the `TextBox`. However, in that context, `Self` refers to the `TextBox`, not to the enclosing user control.

Comment: This hurts my head. You're right, this answers the question, but how? Surely the code behind is `self` yet it appears as if we're searching for an ancester which is 1 level up from this control?

Comment: I'm sorry I can only give 1 * +1, what a wonderfully clear explanation. Thank you

Comment: its easier to use ElementName Binding for this cases - its easier for your head ;)

Comment: @blindmeis: True @head, though YMMV - when inserting many such bindings via copy-and-paste, changing the `ElementName` value to the name of the current user control (unless it is a totally non-descriptive name, which seems somewhat sloppy) is more cumbersome than binding to the next `UserControl` ancestor.

Answer (score 3):

for usercontrols you should never set the datacontext to self. check to comment from H.B. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226843/data-binding-in-wpf-user-controls)

i use ElementName Binding

```
 <UserControl x:Name="uc">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=MyDependencyPropertyDefinedInMyUserControl}"/>
```

using the usercontrol:

```
 <Window>
   <MyUserControl MyDependencyPropertyDefinedInMyUserControl="{Binding Path=MyValueForTheTextBox}"/>
```

i try to explain it a little bit for your textbox case (ignor my poor english btw :))

if you want create a usercontrol with a textbox and this usercontrol/textbox should show the text from differrent viewmodels in different views - then you have a problem as far as the viewmodels have different propertynames. now the dependency property in your usercontrol come into the game. you create a DP where all your viewmodels can bind to and you bind your textbox within your usercontrol just to the DP from your usercontrol.

Comment: If everything binds like this, does it not mean you end up with a big 'god' like ViewModel (which I have no problem with as the data is relevant etc, I just want to get a better understanding)

Comment: the elementname binding for your usercontrol has nothing to do with the viewmodel. the viewmodel binds to the Dependencyproperty from the usercontrol

Comment: I appreciate that, but this still means all of the properties will live higher the tree. Your post has really helped about structuring my project as a whole, so a big thank you. I'm guessing that, all my UserControls should be pretty empty other than DependancyProperties? What about functions/methods/Commands, should they also live where the properties are defined?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you should probably push your parent `DataContext` to the lower levels. This will give you "God" `ViewMode` shared between all nested screens.

Second is that you should probably use something like `MVVMLights` `Messanger` to have cleaner separation.