# Binding a ListView selected item to a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a Page which contains a ListView of users :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </GridVie>
</ListView>
```

I have also a user control which will display all the data of the selected user from that ListView. So I binded the `SelectedUser` to a dependency property `CurrentUser` of `UserUc`

```
<userControls:UserUc CurrentUser="{Binding SelectedUser}" />
```

The user control does not display the data ! Why ?

`Edit`

I added this to the code behind of the page :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedUserProperty = WpfDpHelper.Register<UserListUc, User>(i => i.SelectedUser, Callback);

private static void Callback(UserListUc userListUc, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs<User> DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("user selection changed");
}
```

And when I change the selection of any user the setter gets fired

`Second edit` : The user control

```
<UserControl ...
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentUser.CommentList}">
        <!-- I want to show the user comments -->
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

`Code behind`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentUserProperty = WpfDpHelper.Register<UserUc, User>(i => i.CurrentUser);
public User CurrentUser
{
    get { return (User) GetValue(CurrentUserProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentUserProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: did you look in VS output window for some binding exceptions ?

Comment: Yes I did, there is no errors at all

Comment: Are you sure the `DataContext` is set-up well?

Comment: Does SelectedUser's setter fire PropertyChanged? Can you please post a part of UserUc codebehind related to dependency property in question?

Comment: Does SelectedUser get set by the ListView? I think you need a two-way binding

Comment: @FlatEric SelectedItem binds two-way by default. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried before TwoWay, OneWay, OneWayToSource. Non of them worked

Comment: show your usercontrol code and hopefully you have set the datacontext right there :) i think the problem is your DP binding within your usercontrol

Comment: @KingKing Yes I did checked that. DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Comment: Can you post your code for UserList?

Comment: Try making it a regular public property with a get, set, and notifypropertychanged.

Comment: I see you posted more code.  Implement iNotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I'm using DependencyProperties instead of implementing INotifiyPropertyChanged

Comment: But DependencyProperties is not working so what is it going to hurt to go with NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Blam No it's working I use the all the time, I'm just (maybe) missing something because I use DataContext in both of them. So at runtime it doesn't recongnize which one to pick

Comment: pls check my answer. you simply dont have to set the datacontext to self within a usercontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set the datacontext in your usercontrol to self - thats wrong.
pls use ElementName Binding. So all you have to do is to remove your DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

```
 <UserControl x:Name="uc">
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uc,CurrentUser.CommentList}">
    <!-- I want to show the user comments -->
   </ListView>
```

Comment: You were right sir. I had to remove the DataContrext in the User control. But I don't understand why I can't use the DataContext in both of them ?

Comment: check the comments from H.B. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226843/data-binding-in-wpf-user-controls thats a good explanation :)