# WPF / XAML: Data Binding for UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

So I'm creating "cards" to visually represent a collection of objects within a StackPanel (which I'm using a list to hold these objects):

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window /* ... */>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Deck" Orientation="Horizontal" />
</Window>
```

MainWindow C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    /* ... */
    private void OnDataReceived(List<Reading> readings)
    {
        foreach(Reading r in readings)
        {
            Deck.Children.Add(new Card
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Value = r.Value
            });
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl /* ... */ x:Name="crd">
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Id, ElementName=crd}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=crd} />
</UserControl>
```

UserControl C#:

```
public partial class LoggerRepresentation : UserControl
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

Upon adding one element to `Deck.Children`, its' visual representation does appear in the StackPanel as expected. However, DP seems to lack something as the Labels binding `Id` and `Value` remain empty.

(The idea to give `x:Name="crd"` to my UserControl and then use it within the Binding as `ElementName` has been plugged from [the answer to a seemingly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227155/5410292), but may be misleading in this case.)

Comment: It looks like you're doing things like its used to be in windows programming. you should check MVVM and INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ItemsControl` whenever you want to display a dynamic collection of items.

Replace the `StackPanel` in your XAML markup with an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:LoggerRepresentation />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Bind directly to the source properties of the corresponding `Card` object in the `UserControl` (and replace the `Label` elements with `TextBlocks`):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value} />
```

Create a view model class that exposes a collection of `Card` objects through a public property and move your application logic over to this one:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Card> Cards { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Card>();

    //...
    private void OnDataReceived(List<Reading> readings)
    {
        foreach (Reading r in readings)
        {
            Cards.Add(new Card
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Value = r.Value
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Set the `DataContext` of the view where the `ItemsControl` is defined to an instance of the view model class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

This design pattern is known as Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) and it's *the* recommended pattern to use when developing XAML based UI applications. You will find a lot more to read and learn about it if your Google.

Comment: `<local:LoggerRepresentation />` isn't allowed inside `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>`, but is accepted when I wrap the Template tag in `<DataTemplate>`. Is that correct?

Comment: I still seem to get it wrong, at least I'm getting errors to the output now: 
`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Value' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel' (HashCode=20770076)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=20770076); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`
Is the "Cards" in `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}">` referencing the "Cards" in public `ObservableCollection<Card> Cards { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Card>();`? That's beyond me still

Comment: It should, unless you override the DataContext somewhere.

Comment: How would I ideally add items to the list from the MainWindow now? I've added a function "Add()" to the ViewModel class and am simply routing received items into the Cards property. Is that correct?

Comment: You should use commands. But that's another story. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: The issue is still at hand and errors are still present; DataContext hasn't been overridden anywhere else. Empty cards started appearing only after I turned ViewModel into a singleton class, but I suppose that's straying even further from the solution. I'll let it rest and look at the whole code with rested eyes again, thank you  so far. :)

Comment: Singleton class? What difference would that make? Are you creating several instance of your view model? Put a breakpoint in the constructor to find out. I assume that Id and Value are *public properties* of the Card class.