# WFP - Reuse DataGrid columns and resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an application with two `DataGrid` controls. And although their `ItemsSource` are bound to different collections, their item type, columns, styles and event handlers are exactly the same.

As their XAML codes are growing bigger and bigger, how can I create the same "content" and reuse it in both DataGrids?

What I currently have is:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LeftGrid" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding LeftCollection}" 
         Grid.Column="0"
         CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <!--exactly the same code from this forward-->
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        ...............................
        ................................
        .....................................
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then I have "exaclty" the same datagrid copied whose only changes are `Name`, `Grid.Column` and `ItemsSource` (only the three first rows of the XAML):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="RightGrid"
         ItemsSource="{Binding RightCollection}" 
         Grid.Column="1"
         CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      
    <!--exactly the same code from this forward-->
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        ...............................
        ................................
        .....................................
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Could you use `ControlTemplate`? Been a while since I did XAML...

Comment: @DavidG, I'm quite a newbie with this, so, could I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way at the first glance is to put it to the `UserControl` and use it in the main view.

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNameSpace.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <!-- ... -->
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Which you can use then:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="LeftGrid" DataContext="{Binding LeftCollection}" Grid.Column="0"/>
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="RightGrid" DataContext="{Binding RightCollection}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

If you don't want to use a collection as `DataContext` for the whole `UserControl`, then you can of course create a dedicated dependency property for collection in the `UserControl` and bind it to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`.

Comment: For the original question, your answer is great. But in case anyone needs more properties for the control, this post explains how to add and use them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226843/data-binding-in-wpf-user-controls